# Strange error when trying to run the latest version of php

Tags: php, macos

I followed [this guide](http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/server/upgrading-the-native-php-installation-on-os-x-mountain-lion/) and then I added */usr/local/bin* before the whole `$PATH` variable so that the newly installed version runs first (instead of the default one).
Then when I tried to run `php -version` from the command line, I get the following error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in Command line code on line 1

I am running Mountain Lion.

Comment: What does you PHP code look like ?

Comment: There is no code yet.I must get php to run first.Check my post again if you want.

Comment: It seems that php -v is running fine(I just tried it now and it works).Maybe php -version is deprecated!

Comment: What version is this ...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that php -version is deprecated for php v5.4.x
I tried php -v and it works for both php 5.3.x and php 5.4.x

Comment: Isn't the long option supposed to be `--version`, with two dashes? With one dash I indeed get the same error under 5.4 (not in 5.3) but two dashes works fine.